# How manage multiple users in php chat system?

Tags: php, ajax

How can i manage multiple users in php-ajax based chat system? For example, I have to person 
in server and 10 person from anywhere.I want to manage these 10 person.

Answer (score 2):

This is a VERY generic question, but I built one of these a long time ago, maybe some of what I can remember can help out:

- You'll obviously need an primary key reference for each person.
- Then, I think I had a log file for each current conversation (per person or conversation I don't remember).
- I had a client-side Javascript timeout loop request any changes to the log file. If there were changes, they were returned to that client.
- When the chat was finished / window closed, the log was removed or downloaded or whatever.
- Should probably throttle the system somehow to soften DDOS attacks

---

*EDIT - Second point explained*

The conversation data has to be stored somewhere.  Since you can't access the user's filesystem via their browser, you've got to store everything on your server.  Options are in a file, or a database.  Then, you have to align the stored data to the correct conversation.

Assuming you choose "file", you can organize them either for one user => multiple conversations, or multiple users => one conversation (or one massive file, I suppose, although that would be pretty ugly).

Comment: +1 for giving an answer to a question that's obviously missing about every piece of information available.

Comment: Cheers, a shot in the dark, maybe I'll hit something.

Comment: could you explain the second point?